# floating point exception(core dumped)

Tags: c, floating-point

I tried with putting puts("..") to find where the mistake is, but it didn't help.

this is my third function, first and second are working.
i translated in englih, i hope it's understandably.

```
void write3(sth_st*E, int n, char* Typ){
    int i;
    int sum=0;
    int count=0;
    float result;

    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        if(strcmp(Typ, E[i].typ)==0){
            sum=sum+E[i].time;
            count++;
        }
    }

    FILE*write3;
    write3=open("xD", "w");

    puts("rand");
    result=sum/count;
    fprintf(write3, "%f", result);

    return;
}
```

Comment: I guess `count` is `0`.

Comment: try printing out sum and count before you do the operation. To see what the values are.

Comment: Please post an [Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We can't find problems in incomplete code. For example, how do we know `count` isn't 0?

Comment: Without knowing the types and values of `result`, `sum` and `count` there isn't much we can do.

Comment: learn to use a debugger so you can step through the code

Comment: i edited code, is it better now ?

Comment: Well `Typ` was not found in the `E` array or maybe `n` is too small, so `count` and `sum` both stay at `0` and the division invokes undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

`count` is most likely integer and `0`.  The system error message is misleading, especially since dividing by `0` is perfectly valid for floating point values.

With the extra context, we can infer that `Typ` was not found in the `E` array or maybe `n` is too small, so `count` and `sum` both stay at `0` and the division `sum/count` invokes undefined behavior because it is an integer division.

If you convert one or the other to `double`, you will get a floating point division, which is undoubtedly what you expect and `printf` will print `nan` for this case.

```
result = (double)sum / count;
```

There is also a possiblity that the sum of all times may overflow the `int` type. You should make `sum` a `double` to avoid that.

Note that `%f` is the `printf` format for `double`.  `result` is a `float`, but luckily `float`s are silently converted to `double` when passed to `printf`.  There is no benefit at using `float` types, use `double` instead.

Comment: really? What is the result of 1.0/0? (thats not meant to sound sarcastic - just surprised)

Comment: @pm100: `Inf` (positive infinity).  `(-1.0/0.0)` gives `-Inf` (negative infinity) and `0.0/0.0` gives `NaN` (not a number).  Also `1/-Inf` gives `-0.0` (negative zero)

Comment: Thank you. I really learnt something. Interesting. `printf("%f\n", 0.0/0);` gives `-nan` on my system (Linux, gcc). Do you know why that might be?

Comment: @kaylum: I don't know, I get `nan` for both `printf("%f\n", 0.0/0);` and `printf("%f\n", 0.0/-0.0);`.  What environment are you compiling for?

Comment: Just a standard Linux x86 desktop: `Linux 3.13.0-24-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 10 19:08:14 UTC 2014 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux` and `gcc version 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04)`. And ideone has the [same result](https://ideone.com/DUJlnJ). Anyway, its not important. Was just out of interest.

Comment: i put : result = (double)sum / count; and it gave me a Nan im my file.

Comment: and i tried to put double to sum and it doesn't helps

Comment: Nan is correct output if no entry in `E` matches `Typ`... Investigate why you have no matches.

Comment: @kaylum: weird, my Linux box prints `nan`, with a slightly older version of `gcc` `(Debian 4.7.2-5) 4.7.2`.  You might want to post the question, there are floating point aficionados around here who might have an explanation.